# Why does not this program give an output for any values greater than 3?

Tags: c, loops, binary

I wrote this program to convert decimal integers to their binary form. However, when I give an input greater than 3, the program simply hangs. What is the mistake that I am doing?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,q,r,bin=0,i=1;
    printf("Enter a number:\t");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(q>1){
         q= num/2;
         r= num%2;
         bin=(r*i)+bin;
         i*= 10;
     }
    bin=(1*i)+bin;
    printf("\nThe binary equivalent is: \t%d",bin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things regarding your code:

```
while(q>1){
     q= num/2;
```

1. You didnt initialised q which may or may not enter the while loop.
2. if num is just 4, then q will always evaluate to 2 and will never end and would lead to infinite loop. So you should be checking for `num > 0` instead of `q > 1` and `num = num /2`. something like:

   ```
   while(num>0){
      r = num%2;
      num = num/2;
      bin=(r*i)+bin;
      i*= 10;
   }
   printf("\nThe binary equivalent is: \t%d",bin);
   ```

Comment: How will this work? Just pass some `num` and see whether you get binary equivalent for it

Comment: I tried [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) I am not sure if that's going to remain for you. But i would suggest you try as well.

Comment: I tested my code and it works fine,I was wondering how will this work so tried it but it didn't work as expected

Comment: @Gopi: much the same way as the original code is intended to work.  For a number such as 12 (0b1100), the output value should be 1100 (base 10).  Clearly, there's a rather limited range of value that can be converted like this; if the input is 1024 or bigger, things get problematic (overflow) if the system has 32-bit integers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I was wondering how the range is covered using this logic and also no where we see OP mentioning something related to range

Answer (score 2):

```
int q;
```

is not initialized using uninitialized variable leads to undefined behavior like

```
while(q>1){
```

Check the below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num,r,q,i=0;
    int a[20];
    printf("Enter a number:\t");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(num>0){
         r= num%2;
         num= num/2;
       a[i++] = r;
     }
    for(q=i-1;q>=0;q--)
    printf("%d",a[q]);
    return 0;
}
```